# Unable to create a selectInput of 1 column dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to select a sample of data using selectInput.  I'd like to build a dropdown menu of the specific sample_ids in my dataframe, and use that to subset that sample id from a larger dataframe to graph later.  However, I'm unable to correctly build this dropdown menu.

[Download the two sample files here](https://github.com/raga-muffin/StackOverFlowData)

Create a folder in your working directory named "SampleDataFolder" and upload the .csv files to this folder to run the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

```
library(shiny)

SpadeFiles <- dir("SampleDataFolder", recursive = TRUE, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)   #load .csv files from within "SampleDataFolder"

SpadeData <- tibble(filename=SpadeFiles) %>%
    mutate(file_contents = map(filename,  ~ read_csv(.,skip=3,col_names = c("time", "torque"),
    col_types = cols_only(col_double(),col_double(),col_skip(),col_skip()))))   #mutate file contents

FullSpade <- unnest(SpadeData, cols = c(file_contents))     #unnest file contents

FullSpade <- separate(FullSpade, filename,sep = "/",into = c("folder","sample_id"))     #separate path info into multiple columns

UnqSI <- unique(FullSpade[c("sample_id")])  #create a df of the unique sample_ids

UnqSI[sapply(UnqSI, is.character)] <- lapply(UnqSI[sapply(UnqSI, is.character)], as.factor)     #make the UnqSI a df of factors

UnqSI <- as.data.frame(UnqSI)   #make sure the df is a df

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("ds", "Please select a dataset: ", choices = UnqSI),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[Edit:  Here is an image of my workspace and the app while it is running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZjFO.png)

The cursor flashes in the dropdown bar, but I am unable to see or select the dropdown no matter where I click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same code you provided (except I included the tidyverse library) and got this:[image]

Are you trying to do something different than this?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do!  Good catch on including the tidyverse library.  However I'm still running into the same issue.  When I run the app and click on the dropdown bar to select the dataset, no drop down appears!  The cursor flashes in the box, but I'm unable to see or select the sample_ids as you posted above!

Comment: Hmm, include a print statement for your `SpadeFiles` just to make sure you're grabbing them. Otherwise, not sure why it'd work for me but not you.

Comment: I think I've discovered the issue!  Previously, I had saved my "SampleDataFolder" within my R Project Folder, beside the App folder.  With some print statements, I noticed that the app was not able to read any data at all from the "SpadeFiles" variable.  After I saved the "SampleDataFolder" within the App Folder, I was able to achieve the working dropdown!  Thank you again for your help.